# Changes icon color by using Floating Action Button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, floating-action-button

I want to change the Icon color by using a Floating Action Button. If I press red button, the icon changes into red color.

Code :

```
floatingActionButton: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton.extended(
          icon: Icon(Icons.colorize),
          label: Text('Red'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this (use StatefulWidget widget and setState):

```
class ChangeIconColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ChangeIconColorState createState() => ChangeIconColorState();
}

class ChangeIconColorState extends State<ChangeIconColor> {
  
  Color selectedColor = Colors.blue;
  
  changeColor(Color color){
    setState(() {
      selectedColor = color;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            changeColor(Colors.red);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.colorize),
          label: Text('Red'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      ]),
      body: Container(
          child: Icon(
        Icons.lock_clock,
        color: selectedColor,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

if you want to use StatelessWidget you can use ValueNotifier like this:

```
class ChangeIconColorState extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<Color> selectedColorNotifier = ValueNotifier(Colors.blue);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            selectedColorNotifier.value = Colors.red;
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.colorize),
          label: Text('Red'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      ]),
      body: Container(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
        builder: (context, Color color, child) {
          return Icon(
            Icons.lock_clock,
            color: color,
          );
        },
        valueListenable: selectedColorNotifier,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to use StatelessWidget in second part of answer

Comment: If in my coding already have body for boarder and 'child : Icon (Icons.lock_clock, color: Colors.blue),' how I want to insert ValueListenableBuild ?

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you gotta make sure is that your current widget is a `StatefulWidget`, if you don't know what that is or how to know if your widget is a stateful widget, you should ***probably*** check out a beginners tutorial on flutter.

Now, you need to declare a variable for the color of the icon, and pass that color to the icon:

```
Color iconColor = Colors.blue;
...
Icon(Icons.alarm, color: iconColor),
...
```

next, on your floating action button's on pressed method:

```
onPressed; () => setState(() => iconColor = Colors.red)), // whatever color you want here
```

the `setState` part is important because it tells flutter to rebuild the widget with the new value.